# Jquery hide/show ie8 white space issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, whitespace, show-hide

I'm developing a form where some fields hide and show on click. E.g I have an input field called 'Joint Application?' and if 'Yes' is clicked then title, forename, surname etc fields are displayed. If 'No' is clicked then the fields are hidden.

Functionally this all works fine in all browsers, however in IE8 when you click 'NO' the white space remains underneath where the joint applicant fields have been hidden, therefore you have to scroll down the page to find the submit button. In IE7, IE9, Chrome, FF etc the whitespace is removed as expected and the submit button moves back up but IE8 doesn't seem to for some reason.

Below is the html just using the title as an example to keep this short:

```
<div class="form-row clearfix">
    <label for="jointApp"><span class="required">*</span>Joint application</label>
    <span class="form-icon"></span>
    <div class="form-fields validate-radio">
        <span class="radiolabel">Yes<input type="radio" id="jointApp" class="cdq-jointApp-check jointApp" name="jointApp" value="1" ></span>
        <span class="radiolabel">No<input type="radio" id="singleApp" class="cdq-jointApp-check jointApp" name="jointApp" value="0" ></span>
    </div>
          <span class="tooltip_container">
                    <a href="#" class="tooltip">
                        <img src="/assets/images/tooltip.jpg" alt="joint application information">
                            <span>
                                <img class="callout" src="/assets/images/callout.gif" alt="callout" />
                                Do you wish to add a second person to your application?
                            </span>
                    </a>
                </span>
    <br /><br />
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div id="jointDetails" style="display:none;">

<p class="jointappheader jointDetails" style="display:none">Please enter the joint applicants details below</p>

<div class="jointDetails form-row clearfix" style="display:none">
    <label for="joint_title"><span class="required">*</span>Title</label>
    <span class="form-icon"></span>
    <div class="form-fields joint validate-select">
        <select name="joint_title" id="joint_title" class="cdq-joint-title-text validate-select field-select">
            <option selected="selected" value="">Please select...</option>
            <option value="Mr" >Mr</option>
            <option value="Mrs" >Mrs</option>
            <option value="Ms" >Ms</option>
            <option value="Miss" >Miss</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If it helps my  is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>
<!-- CSS concatenated and minified-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.1" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <!-- end CSS-->

    <script src="/assets/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Javascript is below

```
$('#singleApp').click(function(){

    $('#jointDetails').hide('slow');
    $('.jointDetails').hide('slow');
})

$('#jointApp').click(function(){

    $('#jointDetails').show('slow');
    $('.jointDetails').show('slow');
})
```

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks

Comment: your first tow paragraph is too hard to read please do proper formatting

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to explain better and included the html for the 'Joint Application?' input field so you can see what triggers the hide/show

Comment: Can you post the styles for no-js ie8 oldie

Comment: Not sure there is a specific style for these classes, it's using modernizr, if that helps? I've now included this in the header above.

Comment: Im currently using modernizr 2.0.6, is it worth upgrading to the latest version?

Comment: sounds like basic css issue... without live page is hard to troubleshoot. Post a link

Answer (score 1):

Try the .height() of the element. Try setting height to 0. Try to .remove(). Hopefully this could point you in the right direction; to the actual bug.

Comment: The height of the element is 649. If I set this to 0 then the white space still appears. I've tried remove() but the white space still appears when using this too.